# Unable to declare MotionScene for new MotionLayout

Tags: android, xml

I want to try the new MotionLayot.
But I'm unable to load MotionScreen.

I've added this dependencies to the gradle:

```
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```

and was able to declare motion layout inside xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.motion.MotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/movingCircle"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_circle"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp" />

</android.support.constraint.motion.MotionLayout>
```

But when I'm trying to add a new scene in xml folder, it does not pop up nor clickable to the source.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene //does not popup as a hint. Seems like 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

</MotionScene>
```

What I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: @Vinnie what do you mean?

Comment: @alexeypolusov is this solved to you? If yes, how you got this solved?

Answer (score 2):

Check your `gradle.properties` file and remove this lines

`android.useAndroidX=true`
`android.enableJetifier=true`

Because `constraint-layout:2.0.0` is available only for classic support package

Comment: DO NOT remove useAndroidX=true if you are using this. Instead use this:
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha2'

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed similar behavior.  Currently, it seems like autocompletion and compilation/error checking aren't functional for MotionScenes. It ends up being a lot of trial and error, but I expected about as much from a beta1 release.

Not sure if you want to count it as an "answer", but I've just been writing the attributes I want (constraints, etc) in a layout file and then copying them over.  For something like a `Transition` or `OnClick`/`OnSwipe` you're kinda on your own.

Until it gets further in development, I'd just keep the [MotionLayout docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/motion/MotionLayout) open (and they're actually fairly well done for being in beta1).

You also need to add your MotionScene to the MotionLayout with the `layoutDescription` attribute